# ios get one single file from .zip file without unzipping it

Tags: ios, zip

Now I have a .zip file. it has 1000 JPG images. Now I want to read one of the image out of the .zip file without unzipping it. I can provide the image name which I want to get from the .zip file.

So how to do ?

Comment: not exactly. The link that answer provides is not available. and it also can not show me how to get the specific image file with a image name.

Comment: It's still available, try this link: https://github.com/flyingdolphinstudio/Objective-Zip

Comment: Look at the locateFileInZip method